# Remove blank space between Google+, Facebook, and Twitter buttons

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus

I want my social media buttons (with bubble counts) to sit flush next to each other, but instead there is a random amount of white space between them.  Is there a way to remove it?

Here is the current code:

```
{literal}

<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone size="medium"></g:plusone>
<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);})();
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.url.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" 
data-width="40" data-show-faces="false" style="vertical-align:top"></div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/User" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true" 
data-show-screen-name="false" data-dnt="true">Follow @User</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id))
{js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap each one of your plugins in a div with it's style set to `style="overflow:hidden;width:50px;float:left;"`. Use 50px or whatever width you want. Then you will need one final div to cause a "carriage return/line feed" `<div style="clear:both" />` just after your last plugin's div tag.

Comment: this solution won't actually work once the count bubbles have racked up enough of a count to push the space required for the twitter/google+ button beyond 50px, or 60px, or whatever hard value you set. (changing these px values for every item that uses twitter/google+ buttons so that it looks good by hand would be an impossible task)